# Remove elements in between two specific (HTML) tags in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an **XML input source** as below:

```
                        <p>(U) This product may contain copyrighted material.</p>
                        <h6>BODY</h6>
                        <p>Today, located in Don Chedi District, Suphan Buri Province.</p>
                        <h6>SOURCE DESCRIPTOR</h6>
                        <p>From the Royal Thai by the private company.</p>
                        <p>This product may contain copyrighted material</p>
                        <h6>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h6>
                        <p>The body of this product is a translation of original foreign-language material.</p>
                        <p>From the Royal News section</p>
```

The **output** I required is:

```
                        <p>(U) This product may contain copyrighted material.</p>
                        <h6>BODY</h6>
                        <p>Today, located in Don Chedi District, Suphan Buri Province.</p>

                        <h6>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h6>
                        <p>The body of this product is a translation of original foreign-language material.</p>
                        <p>From the Royal News section</p>
```

I need to remove `<h6>` element which is having value `SOURCE DESCRIPTOR` and all it's following `<p>` tags. There can be more that two `<p>` tags after `<h6>SOURCE DESCRIPTOR</h6>`

I tried something like

```
<xsl:template match="p[following-sibling::*[self::h6='SOURCE DESCRIPTOR']]" />
```

It is giving the opposite result by removing all `<p>` except the required.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed, which makes it difficult for us. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Right. Actually I need to match the tags like this (as input given) only. Because I am applying my XSLT on some already transformed output. Which is the source here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the need to apply XSLT on the given input source (which was already an output of some transformation), I solved it like below which helped to accomplish given requirements:

```
<xsl:template match="p['SOURCE DESCRIPTOR' = preceding-sibling::h6[1]]" mode="xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
<xsl:template match="h6[. = 'SOURCE DESCRIPTOR']" mode="xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <p>(U) This product may contain copyrighted material.</p>
    <h6>BODY</h6>
    <p>Today, located in Don Chedi District, Suphan Buri Province.</p>
    <h6>SOURCE DESCRIPTOR</h6>
    <p>From the Royal Thai by the private company.</p>
    <p>This product may contain copyrighted material</p>
    <h6>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h6>
    <p>The body of this product is a translation of original foreign-language material.</p>
    <p>From the Royal News section</p>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="p-by-h6" match="p" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h6[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('p-by-h6', '')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="h6[not(.='SOURCE DESCRIPTOR')]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('p-by-h6', generate-id())"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <p>(U) This product may contain copyrighted material.</p>
  <h6>BODY</h6>
  <p>Today, located in Don Chedi District, Suphan Buri Province.</p>
  <h6>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h6>
  <p>The body of this product is a translation of original foreign-language material.</p>
  <p>From the Royal News section</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k for the answer but as I mentioned above in the comment I somehow cannot use <root> element to match this because  I am applying my XSLT on some already transformed output. Which is the source here.

Comment: Though I somehow managed to solve it and will post soon. Thanks again.